# Magento 2 - Homepage is 404

Tags: magento2, database, configuration, home

Am struggling with a strange error in magento 2.

Have a setup where i have removed some stores, so now only single store.

Am trying to set the  home page in admin (CMS Home Page)

No matter what I do, it says 404 on home page, all other pages work.

Have looked in database, setting for is: `web/default/cms_home_page` is there and set ok and for scope_id = 0.

not sure which pages it is looking for, is there a way to debug that?

any other suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: did you solve this problem? If so, could you tell me how? I am facing the same problem and it driving me nuts. I have tried so many things but as you said: "No matter what I do, it says 404 on home page, all other pages work." Best regards

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143204)

Comment: Somehow after deleting the empty entires on my multi store config 2.3.3. i now have a Chrome error saying ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS I cleared cookies cache but nothing helps? In the past i have deleted entries without getting this message. Ai...Help

Answer (score 43):

It can happen if one of the products is miss-configured/bad-saved/bad-imported especially `url_rewrite` table is missing `request_path` value.

What i did to fix it...
Open MySQL console & run this query and see which product(s) has an empty `request_path`

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE request_path='';
```

Remove those entities & Clear the cache. Now you can enjoy your homepage ;)

Comment: Another case is Full page cache can’t distinguish GET request from HEAD request. If you do not have cached data or it is invalidated and web crawler send HEAD type request to your site, magento return 404 page and cache it. More here - https://nwdthemes.com/2019/06/28/magento-2-homepage-404-error/

Comment: There should be one things in addition.
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE request_path='/';
remove those

Answer (score 15):

In my case,

The `categories entity` had an empty `request_path`.

Go to the database and with the help of this command find the `categories or products` entities that have an empty `request_path`

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE request_path='';
```

Delete all those entries and use the cache clean and flush command:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Revisit the `url`, and the homepage will work fine once again.

Answer (score 1):

Home page 404 may be solve below way as per your Issue

**Issue: Store Configuration**

Your store configuration point to wrong CMS page.
CMS Home page was deleted or recreated, or you were experimenting with single store / multistore. What you need to do is :

> Login to admin>Navigate to Stores > Configuration>Select General > Web
> tab >open Default Pages section>Set correct value for CMS Home Page
> option

Option value can be overrides on different scope level.

Scope switch located in top left corner. It is recommended to check option value from the Store View scope.

flush the cache in System > Cache Management or via console command

**Issues: URL Rewrite**

Under certain circumstances product or category can have empty request_path value. To fix it:

login to your store database with any database manager ( like phpMyAdmin or HeidySQL )
check if you have any records with empty request path by running following
& delete those entries. It can be done manually or with SQL

```
MySQL> SELECT * FROM url_rewrite WHERE request_path='';
MySQL> DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE request_path=''; 
MagentoCLi>php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

In admin, go to set the page you want to show as homepage in Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page.

Remember to flush the cache in System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache.

Comment: have tried that, it doesnt work. the setting looks ok in database, but not sure how to debug which page it is looking for. also i can see the page that i choose, if i go it its url.

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem?