# Homepage 404 page not found after removing .html suffix in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, html, seo, home-page

I have Magento 2.3 installation on Nginx server.
I removed **`.html`** suffix from configuration by going to

**System > Config > Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization**

[image]

Now the **categories and products** are opening on frontend without **html** but **homepage shows 404 page not found**

I tried clearing all the cache, reindexed all the indexes, deployed static content with no luck.

Do I have to change any Nginx setting to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to question - [Magento 2 - Homepage is 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127960/magento-2-homepage-is-404)

See if there are any records missing value for request path using below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE request_path='';
```

Either remove those records or update with valid values.

Comment: That worked! thanks @rizwan